# 404 Url not found and page not found error php

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Hello Friends I have uploaded one project on server, I am getting  this error page not found and url not found, and .htaccess file is not uploading on server I checked teampage is there on server but still i am getting Url not found and 404 not found error.

```
please suggest something..here i have attached screenshot
```

[image]

Comment: you are requesting a direcotry with your Params

Answer (score 2):

If `teampage` is there on the server, does it have an extension? If it does, you should be using `teampage.html` or `teampage.php` or whatever it is. And avoid the trailing slash you have in the url as well.

**EDIT**

The actual problem OP had was with updating `.htaccess` which was resolved by using cPanel to update it.

Comment: yes it has extension   .phtml but in local everything is working fine and i am not able to upload .htaccess file on server.

Comment: Then you should be using `.phtml` in the url as well. If your local was working due to a `.htaccess` file that did the redirect, you need it on the server too. Maybe you do not have write privileges on the server so you are not able to upload? You must seek write privs for that from your admin/hosting whoever.

Comment: If you have ssh access to the server, why not create the file manually instead of uploading it?

Comment: I am trying to create .htaccess file but it's showing already exsists, but i can't see, I checked very carefully

Comment: Use `ls -la .htaccess` or `ls -la` as .htaccess is hidden due to the .dot in the beginning.

Comment: sorry I am using cpanel, is there any way in cpanel so i can unhide .htaccess

Comment: Of course, please check this link. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-manager/show-hidden-files-in-file-manager

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer. I am capped on upvotes for the day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114134/discussion-between-phreakv6-and-websmentor-com).

Answer (score 0):

If teampage is really teampage.php, then you can access the file using:

sportwitter.techiva.com/teampage.php?tn=ARIZONA CARDINALS

If teampage is a folder and you are attempting to access index.php or some other file within the teampage folder, then you need to specifically list index.php in the url.

sportwitter.techiva.com/teampage/index.php?tn=ARIZONA CARDINALS

If this is a pretty url thing, make sure you have URL rewrite enabled on your server. Upload a file "info.php" with the following code:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Go to sportwitter.techiva.com/info.php on your website. Look for rewrite module in the modules enabled section. If it's not enabled, then you can usually enable it within your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Make sure and delete "info.php" from your server as soon as you find out what you need to know.

Comment: RewriteEngine On is there in my file i am not able to upload only .htaccess file other than this every file i have uploaded.